# How do I limit the current supplied to a boost converter

Tags: current, resistance

I have a power supply that can supply up to 20 amps at 12 volts,  I want to give a boost converter a maximum of 4 amps.  I tried using a 3 ohm resistor but the resistor burned up.  I want to use the power from the boost converter to do anything I need include being able to short the leads without the fuse on the boost converter frying.

[image]

[DROK® 150W DC Boost Converter Power Transformer Module Voltage Regulator Board](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LJXGHC2)

Comment: Can you post some good photos of the chips on the back side? Best way of solving the issue would be to see if the chip supports overcurrent protection and then set it appropriately. Unfortunately, I can't see if that's the case from Amazon photos. 
Pretty much anything else would be more expensive than just buying a converter with overcurrent protection.

Comment: I'm just not really seeing how the circuit is relevant to what im trying to do.  The boost converter itself can only take around 8 amps,  im trying to limit that.  and the only over current protection it has is a fuse.

Comment: I'm asking because you don't see the need. The question gives me extremely strong impression that you're set on doing something the wrong way and are extremely focused on that instead of explaining the actual issue and asking for help to resolve that. Furthermore, the resistor attempt (resistors are **not** used to limit current to variable loads!) and your other questions give me the impression that you don't really know what you're doing and are instead set in your way. A analogy would be: "All I have a rusty spoon, how do I do safe brain surgery?"

Comment: Instead, it might be better to ask something like: "I'm trying to accomplish A. My plan was to do it using B and C, but it didn't work out and D happened. What do I do now?"

Comment: By the way, in case you don't know, a boost converter is a variable load, so you don't limit its current with resistors.

Comment: There are boost converters with built-in output current limiting. Your best bet is probably to get (or design) one of those. Or just go look for one of the well-known "CC/CV" supply designs.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - you don't, at least, not for the reasons you are suggesting.

You said it yourself...

> I have a power supply **that can supply** up to 20 amps at 12 volts

That doesn't mean it **will supply** that much current. The PSU will only supply that much current if the load tries to draw it. If you don't want the load to draw that much current, then that is an entirely different problem.

What do you **really** mean by this:

> I want to use the power from the boost converter to do anything I need
> **include being able to short the leads** without the fuse on the boost
> converter frying.

Do you really want to be able to short the leads and expect no ill consequences? Sure, an external circuit can be used to protect against this, but it's not a trivial task, and the solution has absolutely nothing to do with the converter input current or voltage, rather, it affects the output.

Have you considered just putting a cheap automotive blade fuse on the input or output lines? It will burn out if the converter or load starts pulling too much current and is easy to change. I don't think this is what you are looking for, but without more information, it's about the best solution I can give you.

---

## Questions *YOU* need to answer

---

Since you didn't specify what you are trying to do with this converter, we can only assume you need to power something at a higher source voltage than 12V (your input voltage). You will get a much better answer if you give us some relevant information...

- What is your desired output voltage?
- What will the load consist of (What are you trying to power)?
- Why do you need to limit the current?
- What is your level of electronics knowledge?

Comment: I was looking around and I think what im looking for is an electrical ballast,  thanks for your response!

Comment: That can work, but remember, the ballast will also be wasting a significant amount of power.

Answer (score 0):

Place a large diode between the +  input and the  + output .The diode is to be connected such that under normal operation it does not conduct because it is reverse biased .In other words your set up will work the same as before .Choose a low drop diode like a shottkey . If you use not much more voltage rating than needed your volt drop will be lower . So say a 60V diode would be better than a 200V diode because higher voltage ratings mean more foward volt drop .                The idea is that under fault conditions most of the prospective 20 Amps will flow through the added diode and therefore protect your Boost PCB .Use say a 30 Amp shottkey diode in a TO247 package .The internal diode in your boost convertor wont be anywhere 30 Amps rating .The internal diode also has the boost choke in series with it .This means that the added diode takes most of the fault current protecting the boost PCB.The added diode should be on a heatsink if prolonged short circuit operation is envisaged.